# How can i fix the decrypt function by using fernet crytography

Tags: python, tkinter, encryption, cryptography

I'm trying to create a program that takes title, note and masterkey then encrypt or decrypt that message by using python. But when I'm trying to use decrypt that message by using decrypt_notes func it says "Decryption failed. Incorrect master key" InvalidToken error. How can I fix that?

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
import base64
import os
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet, InvalidToken
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.kdf.pbkdf2 import PBKDF2HMAC

window = Tk()
window.title("Secret Notes")
window.minsize(width=400, height=400)
window.config(padx=20, pady=20)

title_label = Label(text="Enter the Title")
title_label.config(fg="black", padx=10, pady=10)
title_label.pack()

title_entry = Entry(width=30)
title_entry.focus()
title_entry.pack()

secret_label = Label(text="Enter the Secret Message")
secret_label.config(fg="black", padx=10, pady=10)
secret_label.pack()

secret_text = Text(width=30, height=10)
secret_text.pack()

masterkey_label = Label(text="Enter the Key")
masterkey_label.config(fg="black", padx=10, pady=10)
masterkey_label.pack()

masterkey_entry = Entry(width=30, show="*")
masterkey_entry.pack()


desktop_path = os.path.join(os.path.join(os.environ['USERPROFILE']), 'Desktop')
title = title_entry.get()
secret = secret_text.get("1.0", "end-1c")
streaky = masterkey_entry.get()

def save_and_encrypt():
    title = title_entry.get()
    secret = secret_text.get("1.0", END)
    streaky = masterkey_entry.get()

    if len(title) == 0 or len(secret) == 0 or len(streaky) == 0:
        messagebox.showerror(title="Error", message="Please fill in all fields.")
    else:
        password = streaky.encode()
        salt = os.urandom(16)
        kdf = PBKDF2HMAC(
            algorithm=hashes.SHA256(),
            length=32,
            salt=salt,
            iterations=480000,
        )
        key = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(kdf.derive(password))
        f = Fernet(key)
        encrypted_text = secret.encode()
        token1 = f.encrypt(encrypted_text)


        with open(os.path.join(desktop_path, "encrypted_notes.txt"), "a") as file:
            file.write(f"Title: {title}\n")
            file.write(f"Encrypted Message: {token1}\n")
            file.write("\n")

            messagebox.showinfo(title="Completed", message="Your note has been saved and encrypted.")

def decrypt_notes():
    # Get the master key from the entry widget
    master_key = masterkey_entry.get()

    # Read the encrypted notes from the file
    with open(os.path.join(desktop_path, "encrypted_notes.txt"), "r") as file:
        lines = file.readlines()

    # Iterate through lines to find the encrypted message corresponding to the title
    encrypted_message = None
    for i in range(0, len(lines), 3):  # Assuming each note is 3 lines (title, encrypted message, blank line)
        title_line = lines[i]
        if title_line.strip() == f"Title: {title}":
            encrypted_message_line = lines[i + 1]
            encrypted_message = encrypted_message_line.split("Encrypted Message: ")[1].strip()
            break

    if encrypted_message is None:
        messagebox.showerror(title="Error", message="Note not found.")
        return

    # Decode the master key and decrypt the message
    try:
        password = master_key.encode()
        salt = os.urandom(16)
        kdf = PBKDF2HMAC(
            algorithm=hashes.SHA256(),
            length=32,
            salt=salt,
            iterations=480000,
        )
        key = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(kdf.derive(password))
        f = Fernet(key)
        decrypted_message = f.decrypt(encrypted_message.encode()).decode()

        # Show the decrypted message
        messagebox.showinfo(title="Decrypted Message", message=decrypted_message)

    except (InvalidToken, ValueError):
        messagebox.showerror(title="Error", message="Decryption failed. Incorrect master key.")


save_button = Button(text="Save & Encrypt",command=save_and_encrypt)
save_button.config(padx=1, pady=1)
save_button.pack(padx=(10, 0), pady=(10, 0))

decrypt_button = Button(text="Decrypt",command=decrypt_notes)
decrypt_button.config(padx=1, pady=1)
decrypt_button.pack(padx=(10, 0), pady=(10, 0))

window.mainloop()
```

Unfortunately, I couldn't find a solution

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I am not sure, but using differing salts in the encryption and decryption seems wrong to me. I don't know much about the specific topic, but to my knowledge the salt used in the decryption of a given message needs to be same as in the encryption process.

Comment: @PatrickAbraham is correct.  The salt needs to be (1) random and (2) saved with the encrypted data.  You need to use the same salt for encrypting and decrypting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few issues:

- using different salts will create different master keys for encryption and decryption.  Use same salt.
- `token1` inside `save_and_encrypt()` should be a string instead of bytes
- `title` should be read inside `decrypt_notes()`

Required changes:

```py
...

# don't need to get the values here as they are all empty strings
#title = title_entry.get()
#secret = secret_text.get("1.0", "end-1c")
#streaky = masterkey_entry.get()

# create the salt
salt = b'some.secret.salt'

def save_and_encrypt():
    ...
    else:
        ...
        #salt = os.urandom(16)  # don't generate random salt here
        ...
        token1 = f.encrypt(encrypted_text).decode() # make token1 a string, not bytes
        ...
    ...

def decrypt_notes():
    # read title here
    title = title_entry.get()
    ...

    try:
        ...
        #salt = os.urandom(16)   # don't generate random salt here
        ...

    ...
```